# Jquery variable is null or undefined, but pass in validation like be not null or not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, null, undefined

I have this code, that gets repeated "n" times...

```
          <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">
          <fieldset>
              <Legend>Pronto</legend>
              <?php
              $where = '1000,1009';
              $parse=sqlquery($conn,$where);
              while(OCIFetchInto($parse,$campo,OCI_ASSOC)){
                  corpanel($campo['SCORE']);
                  $num_tarefa = str_replace($trocarIsso,$porIsso,$campo['NUM_DEMANDA']);
                  ?>
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h3 class="panel-title">
                          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                              <li>
                                  <a href="#">Tarefa: <?php echo $num_tarefa; ?></a>
                              </li>
                              <?php Alterastatus($num_tarefa);?>
                          </ul>
                      </h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body" >
                      <center>
                          <div id="box-toggle" name="box-toggle">
                            <div class="tgl"> 
                              <?php echo $titulo.'<br/>';?>
                              <label class="control-label" >Analista: </label><?php echo $analista.'<br/>'; ?>
                              <label class="control-label" >Programador: </label><?php echo $programador.''; ?><br/>
                              <label class="control-label" >Data Prevista:</label>
                              <input name="calendario" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" value="<?php echo $data;?>">
                              <label class="control-label" >Centro de Custo:</label>
                              <?php printf("<br/>.$centroCusto.<br/>"); ?>
                            </div>
                          </div> 
                      </center>
                  </div>
                </div>

              <?php } ?>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
```

To get the value of inputs I only can use closest and find. So I wrote this jquery code

```
  <script>
function Alterardata(urlatualizar){
  $( document ).on( "click", function( event ) {
     var numdemanda = null;
     var data = null;
     numdemanda = $(event.target).closest(".inpdem").find("input.valordata").val();
     data = $(event.target).closest(".inpdem").find("input#data").val();
     var link = "/controle_versoes/controle_tarefas/update.php?demanda="+numdemanda+"&dataprev="+data;
     if (typeof numdemanda !== null && !(numdemanda.match(/^\s+$/))){
      if (typeof numdemanda !== undefined){
        window.alert(numdemanda);  
        if(typeof data != null && !(data.match(/^\s+$/))){
          window.alert('não é nula '+data);
          if (typeof data != undefined ){
            window.alert('indefinida' + data) ;  
            window.open(link,"_blank");       
          }
        }
      }  
    } 
  });
}
```

This works, but I have a big problem : the validation does not work! So, when there's no data or a null value, the code ignores the validation and runs the window.open(link,"_blank");

Answer (score 0):

`typeof something` is never undefined and it returns a string. You should write

```
if(typeof data != 'undefined')
....
```

because typeof undefined is 'undefined'.

But, this will let null values pass. The correct way to check for not null and not undefined is:

```
if(data != null)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

according to mozilla docs (found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

typeof never return null.. it is actuall return a **string** as a result so:

```
var x = undefined;

if (typeof x != null)
{
    alert(1); // the alert is poping up!!!
}
```

please replace your validation with "undefined" (insated of null)

```
var x = undefined;

if (typeof x != "undefined")
{
    alert(1); // no alert here :)
}
```